# java generate large prime number using BigInteger and MillerRabin

Tags: java, primes

I'm trying to figure out about how generate prime number using java BigInteger.

We all know that BigInteger has BigInteger.probablePrime(a,b).

It's good, but I want to check the large number using MillerRabin algorithm. Below is a piece of my code:

```
//method to generate random large number
public static BigInteger rand_bigInt(BigInteger n) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    BigInteger result = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rand);
    while( result.compareTo(n) >= 0 ) { 
        result = new BigInteger(n.bitLength(), rand); 
    }
    return result;
}
//method to calculate modular exponentiation
public static BigInteger mod_exp(BigInteger a, BigInteger p, BigInteger m){ 
    BigInteger mod_exp;
    mod_exp = a.modPow(p, m);
    return mod_exp;
}
//method to check the random large number is prime (MillerRabin)
public boolean isPrime(BigInteger n){  
    BigInteger _0 = new BigInteger("0");
    BigInteger _1 = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger _2 = new BigInteger("2");

    if(n.compareTo(_0) == 0 || n.compareTo(_1) == 0){ 
        return false;
    }

    if(n.compareTo(_2) == 0){
        return true;
    }

    if(n.remainder(_2).compareTo(_0) == 0){  
        return false;
    }

    BigInteger v = n.subtract(_1);  
    while(v.remainder(_2).compareTo(_0) == 0){  
        v = v.divide(_2);  
    }

    BigInteger j;
    int t = 5;

    for(int i=1; i<=t; i++){
        BigInteger a = rand_bigInt(v);  
        BigInteger y = mod_exp(a, v, n);  

        if(y.compareTo(_1) != 0 && y.compareTo(v) != 0){ 
            j = _1; //j = 1;
            while(j.compareTo(v) <= 0 && y.compareTo(v) != 0){ 
                y = mod_exp(y, _2, n);  
                if(y.compareTo(_1) == 0){  
                    return false;  
                }  
                j = j.add(_1);               
            }  
            if(y.compareTo(v) != 0){  
                return false;  
            }  
        }  
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Then, I put this in main method:

```
BigInteger randomVal = rand_bigInt(new BigInteger("30")); 
Boolean prime = bia.cekPrima(randomVal);
System.out.println("Random: "+randomVal);
System.out.println("Prime? "+ prime);
```

Result:

```
Random: 11

Prime? false
```

The result is not what I expected.

What's wrong with my code (especially in MillerRabin method)?

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: The BigInteger.isProbablePrime function performs a Miller-Rabin pseudoprimality test. Why do you want to write your own?

Comment: Underscores are not part of the standard Java naming convention.  You should also read the Javadoc about `BigInteger.ZERO`, `BigInteger.ONE` and `BigInteger.modPow()`.